# How to enable allow_url_fopen for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

After updating phpMyAdmin to v4.7.5 on my Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) I'm getting:

> The curl extension was not found and allow_url_fopen is disabled. Due
>   to this some features such as error reporting or version check are
>   disabled.

`phpinfo()` says `Local Value: Off, Master Value: On`

In my `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` I've: `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

I tried `allow_url_fopen Local Value=Off Master Value=Off` but it didn't help.

`php --ini` shows the following files:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

(Of course I `reboot`ed after making the changes.)

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing cURL with this command:

`apt-get update && apt-get install php5-curl`

then

`reboot`

and ready!

Answer (score 1):

Check if php5-curl is installed with one of those two command

```
dpkg -s php5-curl
sudo apt-cache policy php5-curl
```

If it if not try to install it with a:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

And after that you should retart apache server
No need to reboot

Comment: No problem. I was  a bit late sorry for that.